# Need Full Outer Join without having Cross Join

Tags: sql, teradata

Need to join two table without having cross join between them.

The join condition need to be made on Tabl.month = Tab2.month

Input

```
 Table1          Table2
 Month ID        Month ID
 1     a         1     a
 1     b         1     b
 1     c         2     g
 2     d         3     i
 2     e         3     j
 3     f         3     k
```

Output:

```
Month_Tab1  ID_Tab1   Month_Tab2   ID_Tab2
1           a         1            a
1           b         1            b
1           c         Null         Null
2           d         2            g
2           e         Null         Null
3           f         3            i
Null        Null      3            j
Null        Null      3            k
```

The above o/p is required, without cross join, have tried full outer but cross join is happening as the ID is duplicate in both Tables. Left/Right join also cannt be applicable as either of the table might have larger set of ID's.

Comment: Have you tried putting the results into an intermediate table using INTO?  Then you could use a helper column as the lookup to differentiate the IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `full join`, but with `row_number()` to identify the matches:

```
select t1.month month_tab1, t1.id id_tab1, t2.month month_tab2, t2.id id_tab2
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by month order by id) rn from table1 t
) t1 
full join (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by month order by id) rn from table2 t) t2       
on t2.month = t1.month and t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Comment: The join should use month, not id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a full outer join:

```
select
  a.month,
  a.id,
  b.month,
  b.id
from (
  select month, id,
    row_number() over(partition by month order by id) as n
  from table1
) a
full outer join (
  select month, id,
    row_number() over(partition by month order by id) as n
  from table2
) b on b.month = a.month and b.n = a.n
order by coalesce(a.month, b.month), coalesce(a.n, b.n)
```